# How can I give access to upload files on another server in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

When I run the project with Visual Studio, the file upload works correctly, but when I publish the project and run it with IIS, the upload does not work! In addition, the file upload server address (192.168.3.14) is different from the IIS server path (192.168.4.77).
Thank you for helping me.

Comment: `when I publish the project and run it with IIS, the upload does not work` what does mean "not work"? can not find file server or access permission issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several common ways that a web server can store and save files in some folder, but that folder is not on the web server.

A really common approach is to setup what is called a virtual folder.

Say, we have a huge (and low cost) server with boatloads of files. Say, some kind of network appliance. As such, those folders are of course not going to exist on the web server.

So, how do we map web-based URLs to that other server?

The simple (and common) solution is to add to the web site what is called a "virtual folder".

A virtual folder thus looks like other folders in the web site, but in fact the folder "points to" that other server and location.

So, from IIS, you can add a virtual folder by right clicking on the given site. And you can add that virtual folder in a sub folder of existing folders.

Hence this option:

[image]

So, that new folder can be pointed to ANY location.

So, say on some server you have a bunch of PDF documents?

So, then you can add a virtual folder called PdfDocs, and it can point to some server like say \192.168.3.14\files\pdf

So, on the web server, any PDF is now going to be of this format:

```
 wwww.mycoolwebsite.com/PdfDocs/ProductSheet.pdf
```

So, in effect you can map any folder path from any other system that the web server can reach, and once that mapping is done, then those files are available, and appear as a valid path name like any other real folder in your root folder of the given site.

And like always, code behind NEVER used URLs for file paths, but continue as before to use full valid windows path names.

However, you can as before user say server.mappath( "some URL here") to translate that from URL land format to code behind format.

So, say this:

```
 string sInternalFile = 
    Server.Mappath(@"~/PdfDocs/Products.pdf");
```

The above code will in fact return:

```
  \\92.168.3.14\files\pdf\Products.pdf
```

So, from your point of view, and the web site's point of view, then simple valid URLs to that "virtual" folder will work like any other valid URL for that web site.

However, often for reasons of security?

We now as a general rule NEVER allow external URL's to documents or files on the web server. This is done for reasons of security.

In other words, when you need to allow customers to upload some files, but they are of a sensitive nature, then we don't save the file(s) in question to a folder that allows ANY kind of URL mapping to such files.

But then how can we allow the user to see uploaded files, and download them?

Well, we simply use code behind. Thus, when a user uploads a file, we at that time as each file are up-loaded is then save a row in a database. I suppose we could also create some folder on that server based on customer logon id or some such, but it really doesn’t matter. However, we do NOT use a virtual folder, but use code behind.

Remember, when a user up-loads a file, at that point code behind has to save the file, and that code behind does NOT use a URL anymore. Once you changed from web markup to code behind, then code behind does not use URL's anymore, but full valid window path names.

So, after the file uploads, then in code behind, you use .SaveAs "some file name with full valid windows path".

As long as that other server is on the same network, then code behind can save to those folders on that other server. While no valid URL's point to that server, we don't care, since we saved the files into an upload table.

So, when the user wants to download a file, then we display their list of files. When they hit download that file, then once again, we use code behind, and use transmit file. Thus, no valid URLs exist to files, and that enhances security by considerable amounts. So, you can so call steam out files to the user, but they can't type in a valid URL to get to that file.